# How to compare sublist in python

Tags: python, list, compare, sublist

In python

```
a = [1, 0, 0]
b = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]
```

I matching a list `a` with the sublist of list `b`. 
but why printing `any(a in s for s in b)` will return False?

Answer (score 2):

`[1, 0, 0] in [[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]` would return true, as the first list is one of the sublists in the second. Your `any` call is asking if either of the following is true:

- [1,0,0] in [1,0,1]
- [1,0,0] in [1,0,0]

Both are false. What you want is either `any(a == s for s in b)` or (preferably) `a in b`.

Answer (score 2):

With `any(a in s for s in b)` you check whether the list `a` is *an element of* any of the sublists of `b`. While `x in y` will return `True` if `x` is a substring of `y` (or even `y` itself) if both are strings, the same does not work with lists: here, `x` has to be an element of `y`, not a sublist.

```
>>> "bcd" in "abcde"
True
>>> list("bcd") in list("abcde")
False
```

Thus, if you want to check whether `a` is in `b`, you'd have to use `a in b`, or, if you want to use `any`: `any(a == s for s in b)`

Answer (score 0):

Because with `any` you are checking if the list `a` is in a list of strings i.e the sublists from `b`:

```
if [1, 0, 0] in b[0]  #  etc..  [1,0,0] in [1, 0, 1] ...
```

Each `s` in the *any* logic is each sublist in `b`.

when you `if a in b` you actually checking the if `a` is in the list `b` not in  it's sublists.

Answer (score 0):

To match if list `a` is a sublist of list `b`, run

```
a = [1, 0, 0]
b = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]

for x in b:
    if a == x:
        print("YES")
```

The following code will run through list b and if the nested list in b matches list a, it would `print("YES")`